How to setup Couchbase with Quarkus?
I'm using Quarkus 3.12, need to connect my application to couchbase. My goal is to do basic read and write operations.
I found quarkiverse/quarkus-couchbase, they have given the below mentioned dependency on their GitHub.
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkiverse.couchbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-couchbase</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-alpha.1</version>
</dependency>

Getting this error when I try to add that dependency
io.quarkiverse.couchbase:quarkus-couchbase:jar:1.0.0-alpha.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Can you try mvn -U package?

@geoand I tried that, still no luck

Update: Ended up using Couchbase SDK back then and it worked just fine.
